# Couchbase: Why do my views never return more than 22 rows?

Tags: mapreduce, view, couchbase

I have a view defined like this:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  emit(meta.id, null);
}
```

I'm expecting this view to return ids for all documents but it never returns more than 22 documents.  At the moment I have more than 300,000 documents in my database.

I understand that views update asynchronously, but I would expect it to return more than 22 results.  I've tried leaving the database running but it seems like the views just do not update after 22 documents have been added to the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are still using the `dev_` views.  In order to retrieve all the views using a `dev_` view you have to add `&full_set=true` to the list of parameters.  If you wish to retrieve all the results using one of the APIs you will have to publish that view and used the published version of the view instead.

Comment: To add to your comment, the documentation about the different modes is here : http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-types.html